# MYSQL disallow missing fields

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `PersonalInformation` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language_code` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `photo` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `language_code` (`language_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `personalinformation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `personalinformation_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`language_code`) REFERENCES `Languages` (`code-639-1`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I don't want to be able to insert without filling all the files that are `NOT NULL`. Yet still I can perform insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO `PersonalInformation` (`user_id`, `photo`) VALUES (13, 'aaa')
```

and instead of error I get a new entry with empty strings in `first_name` and `last_name`. I enabled strict mode, but still this works this way. Can this be prevented?

Comment: check your `SELECT @@sql_mode`...http://rextester.com/OJQU67820 it works here with `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` would be enabled by default.

Comment: This works, thanks :)

Comment: One more think. Can this settings be exported somehow from phpmyadmin? I would like to have a simple way to import database with this sql_mode set correctly. In exported file I have:
    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
Can I just change this?

Comment: Change it in `my.cnf` so that it is the default everywhere.